# Timed out error in parse cloud when calling an http request inside an aftersave method

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my cloud code I do some things inside an after save method:
send 2 emails in parallel and an http request to create a calendar with google calendar, the problem is when doing the http request to create the calendar it returns a timed out error. I know parse have limits to 3 seconds for after save method, but my question is. How I make requests that last longer than three seconds?

Comment: Sadly, the answer is to migrate to a server you control.  Parse shutting down is good occasion to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overcome the request time-out limit on Parse. Parse is shutting down in less than a year, so you better move to a platform that has longer time-outs. I think on `Backendless` platform, the function time-out is 5 seconds.